# How can I check collisions between actors in pygame using "actor.collidepoint(pos)"

Tags: python, pgzero

I'm very new to pygame and am trying to make a game where the actor try's to hit the gem, but I cant figure out how to use the "actor.collidepoint(pos)" function for that! Answers are greatly appreciated!

Comment: You can look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58717367/how-does-the-collidepoint-function-in-pygame-work)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [Actor](https://pygame-zero.readthedocs.io/en/stable/builtins.html#actors):

> Actors have all the same attributes and methods as [`Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html), including methods like [.colliderect()](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.colliderect) which can be used to test whether two actors have collided.

Supposing you have to `Actor` objects:

```py
player = Actor("player_image.png")
gem    = Actor("gem_image.png")
```

Use `colliderect` method to detect the collision between the actors:

```py
if player.colliderect(gem):
    print("hit")
```

---

For more information about collisions in Pygame, see the answers to the questions:

- [How do I detect collision in pygame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29640685/how-do-i-detect-collision-in-pygame/65064907#65064907)
- [How to detect collisions between two rectangular objects or images in pygame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63561028/how-to-detect-collision-between-two-images-in-pygame/63561152#63561152)